# query issue with datetime and querying between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query here:

```
$result = "SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET WHERE forma.data_fillim >= '".$df."' AND forma.data_fillim <= '".$dm."' ORDER BY forma.id DESC";
```

I get an error like this:
onversion failed when converting datetime from character string., SQL state

Now if i print $dm and $df i get:

```
20130621;20130621;
```

The query works fine if i just put it like this:

```
$result = "SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET WHERE forma.data_fillim >= '20130621' AND forma.data_fillim <= '20130621' ORDER BY forma.id DESC";
```

Someone help please..
Thanks

Comment: what is the datatype of `data_fillim`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try converting **$dm** and **$df**, ToString() when doing the concatenation of the SQL string?

Comment: i just use this...
echo $df=$_GET['df'];
echo $dm=$_GET['dm'];